# Remove expired data from Superfeedr

Tags: json, atom-feed, superfeedr

We use Superfeedr to load current internal job postings from our cloud recruitment software (Newton).  It was just brought to my attention yesterday that positions that are no longer active are still being loaded in our feed.

The raw feed from Newton is correct and it does not have the non-active positions listed.  When I access the feed via Superfeedr the inactive positions are being returned.  When looking at their documentation, it sounds like this behavior may be by design.

Does anyone know if I am correct or if there is a workaround for this?

> **Updates**
>
> If an entry is updated, *they are not propagated by default*. This is
>   because we want to avoid creating numerous false positives.
>
> There is, however, one exception: if a new entry contains a valid,
>   `updated` element, and the update is very recent (within three minutes),
>   you will receive a notification. This means that we will usually
>   propagate updates for feeds if we receive a ping from the publisher.

https://documentation.superfeedr.com/subscribers.html

Comment: Hey! I created Superfeedr. Please, reach out directly and I'll make sure to remove the data manually.

Comment: Will do but if you have to remove the data manually, what happens in the future when our internal postings expire?